# There is a gap at the top of my website

Tags: html, css, styling

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW2t7.png)
[Here is the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrTh.png)
Ok so I want to create a simple portfolio website and I am a bit of a novice with HTML and CSS.

```
    <body>

    <header>

        <h1>Sai Daniels</h1>

    </header>

</body>
```

That's my HTML and my CSS

```
   @import
    url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');
    body{
    font-family: "Raleway";
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    /** HEADER **/
    header{

    color: #00ff6c;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #232323;
    height: 1000px;

    }
```

Even on other questions the answers don't help

I've noticed if I do this it fixes the problem

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

The problem is that I'm the only one that has to do this and I've been told doing that can lead to problems.

Comment: I tried your code and there was no gap. So what exactly is the problem? would be better if you include a screen shot.

Comment: I added a couple photos

Comment: All browsers have default styles applied. For consistent viewing experience across multiple browsers, you can first apply a *style reset* to remove these defaults, and then apply your styles afterwards.

Comment: Add display:inline-block to h1

Comment: How would reset the styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in css

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: agreed, but you should have the class in the css be "header h1" to prevent any other areas of use. Even though you should only use h1 tags once per page for SEO, if there is a different layout that uses that CSS file, you wouldn't want to break that layout.

Answer (score 1):

The `h1` tag has margin by default by many browsers, such as Google Chrome:

[image]

Your code overrides the user agent styles, which is why it works.

I normally use the following code as a quick normalize CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```